# Validate JWT created by a .net core microservice

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, jwt, authorization, microservices

I have some .net core web API microservices running in docker.

For instance: catalog API, postcode api, checkout API.

I created another microservice that validate email and password to generate a JWT token.

Is there a way to check the credentials of this token, in the other services, for example in the catalog API?

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that, I did two things. First of all, In the Startup.cs I Added this code:

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddCustomAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                // -> next three lines: avoid to check de signature key (just the auth app, the issuer, has the key)
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                RequireSignedTokens = false,
                SignatureValidator = (string token, TokenValidationParameters parameters) => new JwtSecurityToken(token),

                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateActor = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true  // -> even avoiding the signature check, the token expiration has to be checked
            };
        });

        return services;
    }
```

And with this code, in the Controllers, I can validate the token without the signature check, just using the [Authorize]

The second step is, when I need to check the signature, I created the [AuthorizeOnJwtSource] attribute:

```
public class AuthorizeOnJwtSourceAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) // -> first, we need to check if we have some toeken
        {
            var authorizationService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<AuthorizationService>();

            string token = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            bool isTokenValid = await authorizationService.IsTokenValid(token);

            if(!isTokenValid)
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

The AuthorizationService use a HttpClient to validate the token in the isser web app.